# SASS - Passing collection to sass mixin as an argument

Tags: collections, sass, mixins

How to pass collection to a sass mixin ?

```
=media($type1, $size1: null)
  @if ($type1) and ($size1)
    @media ($type1: $size1)
      @content
  @elseif ($type1) and not ($size1)
    $collection: $type1
    @media (nth($collection, 1): nth($collection, 2)) <-- ERROR
      @content
  @else
    @error "Upsss...."
```

Use case

```
$m: "36em"
$minw: "min-width
$tablet: ("type1": $minw, "size1": $m)

+media($tablet) <-- ERROR
  p
    font-size: 2em
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I had to use #{map-get($collection, $key-name)} function

```
=media($type1, $size1: null)
  @if ($type1) and ($size1)
    @media ($type1: $size1)
      @content
  @elseif ($type1) and not ($size1)
    $collection: $type1
    @media (#{map-get($collection, "type1")}: #{map-get($collection, "size1")})
      @content
  @else
    @error "Upsss...."
```